# React App stuck on Starting The Development Server on Digital Ocean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, build, digital-ocean

I have tried looking around to see what might be causing my app to not completely build on DigitalOcean. I have tried a few solutions that I have found here to no avail. I have no problem launching my react app locally.

Here is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "first_tailwind_css",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.7.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@tippyjs/react": "^4.2.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.12.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-cookies": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

Where DigitalOcean stops building:

```
[2021-10-22 16:38:33] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 

[2021-10-22 16:38:33] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /workspace/public

[2021-10-22 16:38:33] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

[2021-10-22 16:38:33] Starting the development server...

[2021-10-22 16:38:33]
```

My build commands on DigitalOcean:

```
npm run build
npm start
```

I have tried running the install command before build, but that did not work either.

Comment: May not be related, but `build` creates a production ready bundle in `build` folder, and `npm start` launches a live reload server at `3000` for files under `src` if I remember correctly. So, you are not wrong, but not doing the right thing either. You may want launch a [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) that serves contents from `build` directory at port 80. HTH!

Comment: I see what you mean. `build` compiles the code while `start` is for a local server. I went through the CRA documents again and it mentioned using `serve`. I will try it out to see if it works.

Comment: There is a question here, seems that this issue is not still solved. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-container-building-is-extremely-slow